# Using ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService with aws-codepipeline-actions

Tags: aws-cdk

```js
  // fargate
  const ecsService = new patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'Service', {
    cluster: cluster, // Required
    publicLoadBalancer: true,
    taskImageOptions: {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('nginx')
    }
  });

  // codepipeline artifact
  const sourceOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact();

  // pipeline
  const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline');
  // pipeline stage: Source
  pipeline.addStage({
    stageName: 'Source',
    actions: [
      new codepipeline_actions.EcrSourceAction({
        actionName: 'ecr_push',
        repository: repository,
        output: sourceOutput
      })
    ]
  });
  // pipeline stage: Deploy
  pipeline.addStage({
    stageName: 'Deploy',
    actions: [
      new codepipeline_actions.EcsDeployAction({
        actionName: 'Deploy',
        input: sourceOutput,
        service: ecsService
      })
    ]
  });
```

Using patterns `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` to create fagate service

But, codepipeline_actions `EcsDeployAction` props `service` required type `ecs.BaseService`

How to resolve this problem? Back to build fargae service from scrath ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated !!

Comment: Resolved by using `ecsService.service`

Comment: please add your solution to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` higher-level pattern has a `service` property that is exposed on the instance. The type of `ecsService.service` is `FargateService` which implements the `IBaseService` interface. Your code should work if you change it to :

```
  pipeline.addStage({
    stageName: 'Deploy',
    actions: [
      new codepipeline_actions.EcsDeployAction({
        actionName: 'Deploy',
        input: sourceOutput,
        service: ecsService.service, // <-
      })
    ]
  });
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs-patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html#service

Comment: For anyone searching, this also resolved the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'region' of undefined`